# writing to a file kept in ftp server

Tags: java, file-io, io, ftp, stream

I have a requirement in which I have to write to files kept in FTP server using java ,I cant write to a file in the local server and then transfer it to ftp due to sensitivity of the data,can anyone share some thoughts/links on this.
Any Help will be greatly appreciated.
Apology for not posting my code snippet earlier below is the code I wrote

```
 Student stu=new Student();
            stu.setName("xyz");
            stu.setRoll("12");
            ftpClient.changeWorkingDirectory("/mydirectory/release/");
            //abc.txt is the file on the server
           FileOutputStream fos=(FileOutputStream)ftpClient.appendFileStream("abc.txt");
           ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
           oos.writeObject(stu);
```

Iam not getting any exception ,but also not able to write into the file..
yes I want to upload bytes via ftp from memory..
Thanks

Comment: What is your question? Are you asking how to upload bytes via FTP from memory? Did you look for a Java FTP client?

Comment: Apology for not posting my code snippet earlier,I have tried using ftpClient but somehow not able to write to the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like Apache's FTPClient class, documented [here](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net//apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html), will do what you want.

Comment: I have tried FtpClient but unable to write to the file,I have now attached my code snippet along with the problem..

Comment: Hmm. My best advice would be to pull the file from the server using ftp, write to it, then push it again using ftp. However you did say the file possibly has too-sensitive information to do this. I don't know enough about file transfer in Java to give you a better suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

I got the solution,I had to use url instead of ftpClient

```
URL  url = new URL("ftp://user:pass@myftp.abc.com/myFile.txt;type=i");
URLConnection urlc = url.openConnection();
OutputStream os = urlc.getOutputStream(); // To upload
OutputStream buffer = new BufferedOutputStream(os);
ObjectOutput output = new ObjectOutputStream(buffer);
output.writeObject(myObject);
buffer.close();
os.close();
output.close();
```

Comment: How i can write in that file without overwriting the old data ?